# code error in java array sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

when I run the following program which is to create a random array of integers and then sort them in www.jdoodle.com, I get this error message:

---

```
arr = [18, 85, 93, 81, 8, 7, 18, 26, 46, 41, 69, 48, 50, 16, 3, 26, 27, '\n’      31, 47, 71]

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 20
    at Sort.sortArray(Sort.java:35)
    at Sort.main(Sort.java:10)
Command exited with non-zero status 1
```

---

I just can't find this damn bug. Maybe some of you more experienced out there can take a look at the code? Thanks a lot!

=========================================================================

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Sort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = createArray(20);
        System.out.println("arr = " + java.util.Arrays.toString(arr));

        int[] sortArr = sortArray(arr);
        System.out.println("sorted arr = " + '\n'
        java.util.Arrays.toString(sortArr));
    }

    public static int[] createArray(int l) {
        int[] vektor = new int[l];
        for(int i = 0; i < vektor.length; i++) {
            java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
            int n = r.nextInt(100);
            vektor[i] = n;
        }
        return vektor;
    }

    public static int[] sortArray(int[] inArr) {
        int a[] = inArr;
        int i, j, min, help = 0;
        int minPos = a.length;
        for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            min = a[i];
            for(j = 1; j < a.length - i; j++) {
                if(a[j] < min) {

                    minPos = j;
                }
                help = a[minPos]; // <--- Line 35
                a[minPos] = a[i];
                a[i] = help;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you mark in the code where line `35` is?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
System.out.println("sorted arr = " + '\n'
        java.util.Arrays.toString(sortArr));
```

You're missing a `+` between `\n` and `java.util.Arrays.toString(sortArr)`.

---

Besides the example error, you equate `minPos` to `a.length`, which is equals to `20`.
If your code doesn't enter in the `if(a[j] < min)`, then `a[minPos]` will be the same as `a[20]`, which is wrong: your array have 20 positions, starting from 0 to 19. The last one should be `a[19]`.
You can achieve that with:

```
int minPos = a.length - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
int minPos = a.length;
...
    help = a[minPos];
```

So if none of the code between those two lines changes `minPos` then you'll get this error.

You may mean:

```
int minPos = a.length - 1;
```